# Are Android TV questions considered off-topic for the site?

Tags: support, scope

The question states it all -- Are Android TV questions considered off-topic for the site?

I believe that they are not, since Android TVs and Android does not seem to have that much of a difference in the core of their OSes, but I'd like to ask before I post a question on the main site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Questions about Android TV are certainly on-topic.**

There are some tags related to them already:

- [android-tv](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-tv)
- [smart-tv](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smart-tv)
- [google-tv](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-tv)
- [amazon-fire-tv](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amazon-fire-tv)